# How to refresh UIViewController view on click of some buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing an iPhone app, i have a UINavigationControlller in my AppDelegate.i have refresh button on other view.Button have an IBAction method on clicking a button. i am using this code

```
 [AppDelegate.navigationController.topViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

My problem is how can i refresh my page(reload) on click of these button,setNeedsDisplay method not called view life cycle methods eg. viewDidLoad,viewWillAppear

Am I doing it correct or is there a way of doing what I do?

thanks in Advance.

Comment: don't try to reload viewcontroller, Just try to reload data that you need to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reloading the viewController, you should write a method (or two, or more) that refreshes the data you need to.
That will avoid collateral problems while you add functions later.

Answer (score 0):

setNeedsDisplay does not call into view **controller** life cycle methods like viewDid/Will ... - you are calling setNeedsDisplay on a UIView, not on a UIViewController.

setNeedsDisplay triggers a redraw of the UIView and it's subviews;
put a breakpoint into your view's drawRect: and you will see it is hit when pressing the button.

Comment: i'm using this method - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil, am not using drawRect method now what i do?

Comment: Well, certainly UIView::setNeedsDisplay is the wrong method for triggering your refresh.

Your UIViewController showing the refresh button should implement the IBAction handler method, then the UIButton should trigger that handler method (you can connect that via InterfaceBuilder/xib files or in source code) and the UIViewController can drive the refresh logic, push new data to the UIViews and make them redraw (your [self.view setNeedsDisplay]) afterwards.